# Azure Web App - set custom domain sub directory

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

How to setup `example.com/dir` for a Azure Web App when `example.com` is used on a different hosting provider?

Please note this custom domain URL is **sub-directory** and not sub-domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could use [`Virtual directory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) to do this.

> Virtual applications and directories
>
> To configure virtual applications and directories, specify each
>   virtual directory and its corresponding physical path relative to the
>   website root. Optionally, you can select the Application checkbox to
>   mark a virtual directory as an application.

Please refer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073570/create-virtual-directory-on-same-azure-web-app).

Update:

> Something similar. example.com is already used by entirely different
>   web app, not even hosted on Azure (say hosted on rackspace). Now I
>   want to use only sub-directory (example.com/dir) to one of the web
>   apps on Azure.

No, it is not possible. A domain only can point to a web app. A web app could use multiple domains.

Comment: I'll not have example.com configured on Azure anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I don't understanding what do you mean?

Comment: You only need add a custom domain(like example.com) to Azure web app. Then you could access sub-directory example/dir.

Comment: Do you mean `example.com` had bind to a web app, you could not bind it to new web app? If right, it is not possible.

Comment: Something similar. `example.com` is already used by entirely different web app, not even hosted on Azure (say hosted on rackspace).  Now I want  to use only sub-directory (`example.com/dir`) to one of the web apps on Azure.

Comment: @SarveshGupta No, it is not possible. An A record only works for one web app.

Comment: @SarveshGupta I update my answer. It is not possible. Hope it helps.

Comment: I hope with sub-domain `dir.example.com` this could be possible!

Comment: @SarveshGupta Based on my knowledge, it is also impossible.

Comment: @SarveshGupta Another solution maybe you could use `URL Rewrite` to point Azure web app. Hope it helps.